# How can I export an SVG in Illustrator into a specific resolution PNG?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need exactly 87x87px resolution after I expected SVG, but I do not how how in Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file and choose `File > Save for Web...`

In the **Image Size** area input 87x87.

[image]